# Python C API crashes on 'import numpy' when initilizing multiple times

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-c-api

While working with the Python C API, I found that the python interpreter crashes when initializing it a second time and executing `import numpy` after each initilization. Any other command (e.g. `import time`) will do just fine.

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    while(1){
        printf("Initializing python interpreter...\n");
        Py_Initialize();
        if(PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy")) {
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Finalizing python interpreter...\n");
        Py_Finalize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program crashes on both of my test systems (ubuntu and manjaro, no matter what python version I use) with a *Segmentation Fault* while executing `import numpy` a second time.

The Documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?#c.Py_FinalizeEx) indeed says that:  *Some extensions may not work properly if their initialization routine is called more than once; this can happen if an application calls Py_Initialize() and Py_FinalizeEx() more than once.*

But shouldn't there be a way to properly clear the memory of the interpreter so it can be initialized multiple times? For example if I have a program that allows the user to run a custom python script, it should be possible to run the same script multiple times without restarting the program.
Any clues?

Comment: What about using [Py_NewInterpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html?#c.Py_NewInterpreter)

Comment: It looks like this has been pretty widely reported before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676314/py-initialize-py-finalize-not-working-twice-with-numpy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843408/python-c-embedded-segmentation-fault https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779799/py-initialize-and-py-finalize-and-matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

You can't just declare that all memory should be cleared/reset; Python isn't in control of all of it. Extension modules are actual shared object/DLL files, that can do literally anything a plain C program can do, and they're not required to register all of their actions in such a way that the core Python interpreter knows *how* to undo them on finalization. Python can't know that *this* part of the SO/DLL memory stores data that must be cleared, while *that* part is static data that should be left alone.

It's perfectly possible to run a script multiple times, but you don't do it by finalizing and reinitializing, you just actually run the script multiple times in a single initialization (and hope it's written in an idempotent fashion).

As an alternative, if you're on a UNIX-like box (read: anything but Windows), "resetting" can be done a different way, by `exec`ing your program to restamp it with a fresh run.  This resets more thoroughly than Python itself can, though even then it's not foolproof; e.g. if file descriptors aren't opened in `O_CLOEXEC` mode, they'll stay open in the newly `exec`-ed process.